# How can I classify each comma-separated value of CSS styles so that they can be accumulated?

Tags: css

For example,

I want to make elements like:

```
<div style="
    transition: opacity 250ms linear, background-color 250ms linear;
    "></div>

<span style="
    transition: opacity 250ms linear, color 250ms linear;
    "></span>
```

, and ***classify* the styles to make them(*CSS classes*) easy to reuse:**

```
.smooth-opacity-change {transition: opacity 250ms linear;}
.smooth-color-change {transition: color 250ms linear;}
.smooth-background-color-change {transition: background-color 250ms linear;}
```

; then I could write it:

```
<div class="smooth-opacity-change smooth-background-image-change"></div>

<span class="smooth-opacity-change smooth-color-change"></span>
```

But they're exclusive; `transition` style can have multiple values, however only one *`transition` style* can be applied.

How can I solve this problem, or is it discouraged *by design*?

Comment: Some years ago this has been asked already ([Adding transition to a different property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23612740/3162554), [Stack CSS Transitions using multiple classes without overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16888312/3162554)) and I'm afraid there is not yet another solution than [writing down all possible combinations of transition-properties](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhnvf336/). Could be simplified to a few lines by using a pre-processor but the CSS would be the same in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comment, [Marvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3162554/marvin). Unfortunately, it seems that CSS *still* have a long way to go. I wish someday we could experience the evolution of web styling.

> Some years ago this has been asked already ([Adding transition to a different property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23612740/3162554)) and I'm afraid there is not yet another solution than **writing down all possible combinations of transition-properties**. Could be simplified to a few lines by **using a pre-processor** but **the CSS would be the same in the end**. -- [Marvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3162554/marvin)

```
/* Writing down all possible combinations of transition-properties */
.smooth-transition {transition-duration: 250ms; transition-timing-function: linear}
.opacity-transition {transition-property: opacity}
.background-color-transition {transition-property: background-color}
.opacity-transition.background-color-transition {transition-property: opacity, background-color}
```